# Error joining AS2 with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have problems joining two scripts into one.

[This is main part of the script: AS3.](http://pastebin.com/XCV7YLbi)

[And this is already joined script.](http://pastebin.com/Rx8vYzK0)

And here is part of the code that I need to import (AS2) :

```
stop();
var banners:Array = new Array();
var imagePaths:Array = new Array();
var links:Array = new Array();
var bodyTexts:Array = new Array();
var imageTime:Number;
var numberOfBanners:Number;
var isRandom:String;
var showHeader:String;
var bannersXML:XML = new XML();
bannersXML.ignoreWhite = true;
bannersXML.load("banners.xml");
bannersXML.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        trace("XML LOADED");
        imageTime = parseInt(this.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild)*1000;
        numberOfBanners = parseInt(this.firstChild.childNodes[1].firstChild);
        isRandom = this.firstChild.attributes["isRandom"];
        showHeader = this.firstChild.childNodes[2].attributes["showHeader"];

        var bannerSequence:Array = new Array();
        if (isRandom == "true") {
            //Make a random sequence
            while (bannerSequence.length<numberOfBanners) {
                newRandomNumber = random(numberOfBanners);
                //Make sure that the random one chosen is not already chosen
                for (var i = 0; i<=bannerSequence.length; i++) {
                    if (newRandomNumber != bannerSequence[i]) {
                        alreadyThere = false;
                    } else {
                        alreadyThere = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //Add only random values that aren't in the array
                if (!alreadyThere) {
                    bannerSequence.push(newRandomNumber);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i<numberOfBanners; i++) {
                bannerSequence.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    //Read XML in the Random Order Chosen
    for (var i = 0; i<numberOfBanners; i++) {
        banners.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].firstChild.firstChild.toString());
        bodyTexts.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
        imagePaths.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue);
        links.push(this.firstChild.childNodes[2].childNodes[bannerSequence[i]].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
    play();
};
//Start the image counter at 0
var imageCounter = 0;
```

I get erorr in this part of the code

```
function doRandArray(a:Array):Array {//make random array
 var nLen:Number = a.length;
 var aRand:Array = a.slice();
 var nRand:Number;
 var oTemp:Object;
 for (var i:Number = 0; i < nLen; i++) {
  oTemp = aRand[i];
  nRand = i + (random(nLen – i));
  aRand[i] = aRand[nRand];
  aRand[nRand] = oTemp;
 }
 return aRand;
}
```

When I run it, I get an error in this place:

```
nRand = i + (random(nLen – i));
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 265 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before i.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as2 `random(random(nLen – i));` is generate 0,1,...nLen-i-1. not floating only int value.

correct as3 code is `int(Math.random()*(nLen-i));` or `Math.floor(Math.random()*(nLen-i));`

as2: [random()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7a36.html)

as3: [Math.random()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29)

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that nRand's type was Number instead of int, which would've made the floor happen automatically when assigned. I guess I assumed it was an uint since I always use that type for array index variables :P Anyways, thanks for the correction.

Comment: You do realize that he is just using that value to access an array and since arrays only accept int values, the value is automatically truncated and the functionality would be exactly the same...

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Fixed it. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score -1):

In **ActionScript 3** the [random](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29) function is a little bit different from what it was in as2 code, just change the offending line to:

```
nRand = i + Math.random()*(nLen-1);
```

This should fix all errors and work just the same.

EDIT: as @bitmapdata.com indicated, for this to run the same as in as2 the random value must be truncated (stripped of its decimal values). Besides the couple of possibilities he suggested, I would personally just change nRand's type to uint on declaration:

```
var nRand:uint;
```

You can also change the iterator type to `var i:uint`. Less memory usage is always good ;)

Comment: Hi maybe u can pm me in Titasss4@gmail.com i still get some erorrs. If u can make this script working we could arange some payment for ur help. If u are interested.